# How to run the testng.xml with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng

i Have testng.xml with all my test classes. i want to run that testng.xml with jenkins.

can any body help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use **Jenkins**?

You run the command the same way you run it from command line. ANT, Maven or Java call.
Jenkins can run the same command (as a Build step) and by adding the [TestNG](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) plugin it can report the results on the post build step.

I hope this helps.